# OBIEE Master and Detail relationship

Tags: master-detail, linechart, obiee

I am trying to create some reports using the master/detail functionality. I tried this using a table and bar graph, a table and line chart, and it's working fine.

Now I am trying to build master/detail functionality between a bar graph and line chart using a slider but it's not working. How can you set up the master/detail functionality without using a table.

Comment: Master-detail only works on text labels.

As of versión 11.1.1.7.1, clicking on the bars,lines,bubbles/etc. does not trigger the master-detail event. You must click the axis lables on your graph; if the master atribute is used in the "Color by" section, you must include a legend and click on the legend labels.

Comment: Thank you victor for giving this information to me.

Comment: You are welcome, I posted as a comment first because CAPTCHA was misbehaving

Answer (score 1):

Master-detail only works on text labels.

As of versión 11.1.1.7.1, clicking on the bars,lines,bubbles/etc. does not trigger the master-detail event. You must click the axis lables on your graph; if the master atribute is used in the "Color by" section, you must include a legend and click on the legend labels.